# Mongoose returning empty array of ObectID, which isn't

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the following Mongoose `Schema` :

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  ...

  sentFriendsRequests: [{
    type : ObjectId,
  }]

)};
```

I am adding some `ObjectIds` to the `sentFriendsRequests`

```
User.update({ _id: userId },
    { $push: { sentFriendsRequests: targetId }},
    {safe: true, upsert: true}, function(err, result) {
       if (err || !result) {
          done(err);
       }
       done(null);
});
```

This seems to be working properly, because as I am using Mongolab to host my Database, when displaying documents on screen I can see that the `ObjectIds` are added to the array with success :

```
"receivedFriendsRequests": [
   "5720c659571a718705d58fc3"
]
```

The weird thing is that when querying this array, Mongoose always return an empty one...

```
User.find({ _id: userId}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res[0].sentFriendsRequests);
});
// prints []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have confusion of **mongodb** with **mongoose**.

Mongoose need define Schema but mongodb is nope.

To define new ObjectId in mongodb:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var objectId = new ObjectID();
```

in Mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that using `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;` makes Mongoose to return empty array, whereas using `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` works properly. I don't know how to explain this.